# Creating flash slideshlow c#

Tags: c#, flash

We have a few flash files f1.swf, f2.swf .... fn.swf.
We would like to be able to display a slide show of these different files in c# using winforms.
Each flash file is a slideshow by itself. At the end of slideshow for f1 we need to display a message and ask the user to repeat it or continue. Just wondering if anyone has any suggestions how to achieve this.
Thanks
N

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for: **[How to Play Flash (SWF) inside C#](http://fci-h.blogspot.com/2007/06/how-to-play-flash-swf-inside-c.html)**

EDIT: 
also here is some interesting stuff: **[Example C# Code for Reading Flash (SWF) Files](http://blogs.msdn.com/mswanson/archive/2006/10/15/example-c-code-for-reading-flash-swf-files.aspx)**

Comment: Lukas Thanks for your response i got that successfully in other words i am able to load a single flash file successfully. But after it reaches its end we would like to display a message to the user asking him if he needs to replay or continue to next file. Please let me know ifyou have any suggestions.

Edit: Mike Swansons swf to xaml did not help me it was throwing exceptions when i try to convert smeof my swf files.

Thanks
N